# Performance issues on new instalation (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Tags: google-chrome, performance, youtube

I recently formatted my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 because I had an older installation of it that was running slow.
Every so often I get some kind of lag using the system. I might be just navigating some folders, browsing the web or any sort of task really.
Lately I have been editing videos with Shotcut, which is a more demanding task for my laptop but it runs ok 90% of the time. Then for some unknown reason I get this long freezes that I have to wait for 5 minutes or more for the system to respond.

Also I am having trouble with videos on YouTube. The playback stutters every so often, no matter the resolution.
I was using Firefox but installed Chrome to see if that could be an issue just with the browser.

This issue occurs even with a video that I uploaded myself to Youtube. Locally, through VCL the video is smooth, but not at YouTube.

Is there a way to check if I have a hardware problem? Something I could double check to see if there is some kind of issue?

Here are my specs:

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- Memory: 7,6 GiB
- Disk: 250GB SSD
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit
- GNOME: 3.36.8

Also, my RAM never seems to go higher then maybe 4 GiB (I ran a command line utility meant to use up all my RAM and indeed it went up, but still..)

Also, Also, while typing this very question I experienced performance drops (my keystrokes would lag, the System Monitor screen would freeze, specially if I moved it, etc). But again, CPU usage and RAM allocation never spiked).

[image: System monitor]

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if there are errors being reported around the time of the slowdowns? How is your I/O (disk activity) during these freezes?

Comment: Which logs? Sorry for the newbie questions. Also, how would you suggest I check the disk activity? Do you know any particular tool that you like for that?

Comment: @DSaita I also experienced this one, have you managed to solve this issue?